# How to move to trash an e-mail without deleting it with Mailkit?

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mailkit

I'm still mastering the amazing Mailkit library, but there is something that blows my mind.

By the moment, if I add a flag to a concrete UID it gets automatically deleted 
by using `ImapClient.Inbox.AddFlags(uid, MessageFlags.Deleted, false)`.

I want to give the option to the user to move the message to the trash folder. The thing is that I find no standard to throw the e-mail to the trash folder. Firstly because my trash folder on my own mailserver is named "Trash" but...

1. Is there any standard to move the e-mail directly to trash? I guess the trash could be named as "My bin", "Trash" or even "Papelera" in other languages
2. With previous thing asked... is there any way to get the "default trash route"? In my GMail the trash is in "[GMail]/Papelera" but on my own mailserver is placed on the toplevel /Trash. That could be really useful in cases like this one.

The .AddFlags is quite useful but sounds so killer for me :'D

EDIT: I could actually check if I'm connecting to GMail by using

```
string capab = ImapClient.Capabilities.ToString();         
if(capab.Contains("GMail"))
{
    pain=true;
}
```

but doesn't sound this is the best way to hold this situation.

Thanks in advance,
Gonzo345.

Comment: Some servers support SPECIAL USE extensions, which indicate which folders are for special use (trash, drafts, etc.) in tags in the LIST response.  Gmail is one of them.  For others, you have to guess.

Comment: As @Max said, GMail supports the `SPECIAL-USE` extension which means that MailKit will return the correct folder if you call `ImapClient.GetFolder (SpecialFolder.Trash)`. To check if this feature is supported by your IMAP server, check `if (ImapClient.Capabilities.HasFlag (ImapCapabilities.SpecialUse))`